# Getting word count from a dataframe of selected words in python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with reviews in it and I want to get how many of a specific word is in each review.

For example dataframe is like this:

```
['good food', 'great staff', 'great food and great staff']
```

And if I search for the word 'great' the result should be an added df column:

```
count
0
1
2
```

So far I tried this but it is not working:

```
counter = defaultdict(int)
great = 'great'
with open('Reviews.csv', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    next(f)  # for skip first row with headers
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        df['Count'] = counter(great)
```

Comment: Also, you should first look up how to add a column based on existing columns.  There are many examples on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't defined `df` anywhere, you're just looping over lines in a `.csv`.

If you want to work with a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) that is conventionally referenced as `df`, you'll need to `pip install pandas` at your command line. Then, you can use [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to get a data structure with a nice interface. Then you can get reviews by subscripting `df["name_of_review_col"]`. You can iterate over those rows, split each review on it's whitespace (`" "`) and using a `Counter()` from `collections.Counter`, count all the unique words in each review.